# Ride dyalog apl multiline dfn unpaired brace

Tags: apl, dyalog, dyalog-ride

```
      ]dinput
·   f ← {
·   ·   1
·   }
      f←{
SYNTAX ERROR: Unpaired brace
      f←{
        ∧
```

How can I enable the `]dinput` multi-line functionality by default in Ride?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the configuration parameter `LINEEDITOR_MODE=1`.

This can be done [any number of ways](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#UserGuide/Installation%20and%20Configuration/Configuration%20Parameters.htm), including through the RIDE connection screen:
[image: screenshot of setting the configuration parameter]

While the result looks slightly different from when using `]DInput`, the functionality is much the same:

```
      f ← {
       1
      }
      f ⍬
1
```